# Import-SPWeb: Document library Import Failed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, import

I am doing document library import by using Import-SPWeb command but it failed with below error. There was no error or warning in Export process.

> Error: Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again. [5/25/2017 11:27:02 AM] [List] [docs]   Debug:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String
>   schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op, Boolean
>   isMigration, Boolean fResetCTCol)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String
>   schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.CreateOrUpdateField(SPList
>   list, String fieldName, XmlNode fieldNode)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.UpdateListFields(SPList
>   list, Dictionary`2 listMetaData)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.SetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector) [5/25/2017 11:27:02 AM] FatalError:
>   Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again. [5/25/2017 11:27:02 AM] Debug:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String
>   schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op, Boolean
>   isMigration, Boolean fResetCTCol)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String
>   schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.CreateOrUpdateField(SPList
>   list, String fieldName, XmlNode fieldNode)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.UpdateListFields(SPList
>   list, Dictionary`2 listMetaData)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.SetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type
>   objectType, Boolean isChildObject)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type
>   objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run() [5/25/2017 11:27:05 AM]
>   Progress: Import did not complete.

Comment: Could you add the command and parameters you used to import the document library?

Comment: Also please check that you have the required site collection features and site features at the destination location. You can do comparison between source and destination to spot possible differences.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But issue got resolved after rerunning the import command. I don't know the root cause for this.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Does your destination site collection and site have the required site collection features and site features for your document library type? You can do a comparison between the source and the destination locations if you are unsure which features should be activated.
- Did your export process create more than one files? If yes, the exported site exceeded a default file size limit, which can be increased in the export-process by using `-CompressionSize <insert megabyte limit up to 1024 MB>`

Comment: Thanks for reply.But issue got resolved after rerunning the import command. I don't know the root cause for this.